# Convert 12-bit Bayer image to 8-bit RGB using OpenCV

Tags: image, opencv, rgb

I am trying to use OpenCV 2.3.1 to convert a 12-bit Bayer image to an 8-bit RGB image. This seems like it should be fairly straightforward using the cvCvtColor function, but the function throws an exception when I call it with this code:

```
int cvType = CV_MAKETYPE(CV_16U, 1);
cv::Mat bayerSource(height, width, cvType, sourceBuffer);
cv::Mat rgbDest(height, width, CV_8UC3);
cvCvtColor(&bayerSource, &rgbDest, CV_BayerBG2RGB);
```

I thought that I was running past the end of sourceBuffer, since the input data is 12-bit, and I had to pass in a 16-bit type because OpenCV doesn't have a 12-bit type. So I divided the width and height by 2, but cvCvtColor still threw an exception that didn't have any helpful information in it (the error message was "Unknown exception").

There was a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7598854/how-do-i-convert-bayer-to-rgb-using-opencv-and-vice-versa) posted a few months ago that was never answered, but since my question deals more specifically with 12-bit Bayer data, I thought it was sufficiently distinct to merit a new question.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**: I must be missing something, because I can't even get the cvCvtColor function to work on 8-bit data:

```
cv::Mat srcMat(100, 100, CV_8UC3);
const cv::Scalar val(255,0,0);
srcMat.setTo(val);
cv::Mat destMat(100, 100, CV_8UC3);
cvCvtColor(&srcMat, &destMat, CV_RGB2BGR);
```

Comment: So it turns out that I *was* missing something. My colleague pointed out that I was mixing C and C++ calls. Changing the last line to

    cv::cvtColor(srcMat, destMat, CV_RGB2BGR);

made everything work like a charm. I'm still working on the original problem of converting 16-bit Bayer data to 8-bit RGB data, so I'll post an update if I find the answer to that.

Comment: `cvCvtColor` belongs to old C OpenCV API, but `cv::Mat` is a class from C++ API. Mixing them is not a good idea and you'd better use only one version of API. `cv::cvtColor(srcMat, dstMat, COLOR_RGB2BGR)` should work for you.

Comment: "Green filter look" probably means you have specified the wrong Bayer pattern. Try them all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Gillfish's answer technically works but during the conversion it uses smaller data structure (CV_8UC1) than the input (which is CV_16UC1) and loses some color information.

I would suggest first to decode the Bayer encoding but stay in 16-bits per channel (from CV_16UC1 to CV_16UC3) and later convert to CV_8UC3.

The modified Gillfish's code (assuming the camera gives image in 16bit Bayer encoding):

```
// Copy the data into an OpenCV Mat structure
cv::Mat mat16uc1_bayer(height, width, CV_16UC1, inputBuffer);

// Decode the Bayer data to RGB but keep using 16 bits per channel
cv::Mat mat16uc3_rgb(width, height, CV_16UC3);
cv::cvtColor(mat16uc1_bayer, mat16uc3_rgb, cv::COLOR_BayerGR2RGB);

// Convert the 16-bit per channel RGB image to 8-bit per channel
cv::Mat mat8uc3_rgb(width, height, CV_8UC3);
mat16uc3_rgb.convertTo(mat8uc3_rgb, CV_8UC3, 1.0/256); //this could be perhaps done more effectively by cropping bits
```

Comment: I scratched my head for hours wondered why it wasn't working util I realized that I was working with big endian data while opencv expects little endian ...

Answer (score 15):

I was able to convert my data to 8-bit RGB using the following code:

```
// Copy the data into an OpenCV Mat structure
cv::Mat bayer16BitMat(height, width, CV_16UC1, inputBuffer);

// Convert the Bayer data from 16-bit to to 8-bit
cv::Mat bayer8BitMat = bayer16BitMat.clone();
// The 3rd parameter here scales the data by 1/16 so that it fits in 8 bits.
// Without it, convertTo() just seems to chop off the high order bits.
bayer8BitMat.convertTo(bayer8BitMat, CV_8UC1, 0.0625);

// Convert the Bayer data to 8-bit RGB
cv::Mat rgb8BitMat(height, width, CV_8UC3);
cv::cvtColor(bayer8Bit, rgb8BitMat, CV_BayerGR2RGB);
```

I had mistakenly assumed that the 12-bit data I was getting from the camera was tightly packed, so that two 12-bit values were contained in 3 bytes. It turns out that each value was contained in 2 bytes, so I didn't have to do any unpacking to get my data into a 16-bit array that is supported by OpenCV.

**Edit:** See @petr's improved answer that converts to RGB before converting to 8-bits to avoid losing any color information during the conversion.

Comment: I am doing the same as here but my images seem to have a green filter ontop of the image. not sure why

Comment: @pksorensen: If you have a related issue, just ask it in a new question and link back to this one. That way you can add more details about your particular problem.

Comment: I ended up taking a different path and using the Nikon SDK for doing the de-bayer as I faced a few issues trying to do it with libraw and opencv. Using nikons SDK gave me better results and figuring out why the same results could not be achived with libraw and opencv must wait. Thanks anyway.

Comment: But using 0.0625 you otherwise "chop off the low order bits" (X/16  is the same as bit shift X>>4). So it is better just ask camera to send 8-bit picture and keep CPU cooler. One need more sophisticated compression method like old good HDR(slow) or simple curves(fast) to avoid 4bit information loosing while 16(12) bit ->8 bit compression.

Comment: @VitShiryaev That would be great if I could ask the camera to send me the files in the format that I needed them in, but in this case I only had access to the files, not the camera itself.

Comment: Awesome work! This is what I was looking for. However I also have green filter issue like @Poul. Is it solved or asked in a new question?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone struggling with this, the above solution only works if your image actually comes in 16bit otherwise, as already suggested by the comments you should chop-off the 4 least significant bits. I achieved that with this. It's not very clean but it works.

```
unsigned short * image_12bit = (unsigned short*)data;
char out[rows * cols];

for(int i = 0; i < rows * cols; i++) {
  out[i] = (char)((double)(255 * image_12bit[i]) / (double)(1 << 12));
}

cv::Mat bayer_image(rows, cols, CV_8UC1, (void*)out);
cv::cvtColor(bayer_image, *res, cv::COLOR_BayerGR2BGR);
```