# Trying to extract pixel values from a given PNG image

Tags: image, image-processing, opencv, png, imagecreatefrompng

**Trying to understand PNG format.**

Consider this PNG Image:

[image]

The Image is taken from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:PNG-Gradient.png)

In Hex Editor , it looks like this:

```
89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A 00 00 00 0D 49 48 44 52 00 00 00 80 00 00 00 44 08 02 00 00 00 
C6 25 AA 3E 00 00 00 C2 49 44 41 54 78 5E ED D4 81 06 C3 30 14 40 D1 B7 34 DD FF FF 6F 
B3 74 56 EA 89 12 6C 28 73 E2 AA 34 49 03 87 D6 FE D8 7B 89 BB 52 8D 3B 87 FE 01 00 80 
00 00 10 00 00 02 00 40 00 00 08 00 00 01 00 20 00 00 04 00 80 00 00 10 00 00 02 00 40 
00 00 08 00 00 01 00 20 00 00 00 D4 5E 6A 64 4B 94 F5 98 7C D1 F4 92 5C 5C 3E CF 9C 3F 
73 71 58 5F AF 8B 79 5B EE 96 B6 47 EB F1 EA D1 CE B6 E3 75 3B E6 B9 95 8D C7 CE 03 39 
C9 AF C6 33 93 7B 66 37 CF AB BF F9 C9 2F 08 80 00 00 10 00 00 02 00 40 00 00 08 00 00 
01 00 20 00 00 04 00 80 00 00 10 00 00 02 00 40 00 00 08 00 00 01 00 20 00 00 8C 37 DB 
68 03 20 FB ED 96 65 00 00 00 00 49 45 4E 44 AE 42 60 82
```

Equivalent characters:

```
‰PNG........IHDR...€...D.....Æ%ª>...ÂIDATx^íÔ..Ã0.@Ñ·4Ýÿÿo³tVê‰.l(sâª4I.‡ÖþØ{‰
»R.;‡þ..€.......@....... ....€.......@....... ...Ô^jdK”õ˜|Ñô’\\>Ïœ?sqX_¯
‹y[î–¶GëñêÑÎ¶ãu;æ¹•.ÇÎ.9É¯Æ3“{f7Ï«¿ùÉ/.€.......@....... ....€.......@....... ..Œ7Ûh. 
ûí–e....IEND®B`‚
```

The same is shown in following Screenshot of the HEX Editor:

[image]

I am trying to reverse engineer this image to extract the header part and the RGB pixel values.  I read about the [PNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) and also [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG-Chunks.html) , and so far I have noted the following about this Image:

The IHDR chunk must appear FIRST. It contains:

```
Width:              4 bytes
Height:             4 bytes
Bit depth:          1 byte
Color type:         1 byte
Compression method: 1 byte
Filter method:      1 byte
Interlace method:   1 byte
```

**Below I am starting reading the HEX Data in sequence:**

**1-  First 8-bytes: This is the 8-Byte signature**

```
 89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A
```

Equivalently this is :  %PNG as can be seen in HEX Editor

A valid PNG image must contain an IHDR chunk, one or more IDAT chunks, and an IEND chunk.

**2-  Chunk:  Length**

```
 00 00 00 0D
```

**3-Chunk: Chunk Type**

```
 49 48 44 52
```

Which is IHDR.

http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG-Chunks.html

**4-  Chunk: Width of the Image (in Decimal 128)**

```
00 00 00 80
```

**5- Chunk: Height of the image (in Decimal 68)**

```
00 00 00 44
```

**6- Chunk: BIT DEPTH (1 byte )**

```
08
```

**7- Chunk: Color Type**

```
02
```

**8- Compression method**

```
00
```

**9- Filter method:**

```
00
```

**10- Interlace method:**

```
00
```

***11-  What is the following data?***

C6 25 AA 3E 00 00 00 C2

**12-- IDAT**

49 44 41 54

***13- What is this data (after IDAT):***

78 5E ED D4 81 06 C3 30 14 40 D1 B7 34 DD FF FF 6F B3 74 56 EA 89 12 6C 28 73 E2 AA 34 49 03 87 D6 FE D8 7B 89 BB 52 8D 3B 87 FE 01 00 80 00 00 10 00 00 02 00 40 00 00 08 00 00 01 00 20 00 00 04 00 80 00 00 10 00 00 02 00 40 00 00 08 00 00 01 00 20 00 00 00 D4 5E 6A 64 4B 94 F5 98 7C D1 F4 92 5C 5C 3E CF 9C 3F 73 71 58 5F AF 8B 79 5B EE 96 B6 47 EB F1 EA D1 CE B6 E3 75 3B E6 B9 95 8D C7 CE 03 39 C9 AF C6 33 93 7B 66 37 CF AB BF F9 C9 2F 08 80 00 00 10 00 00 02 00 40 00 00 08 00 00 01 00 20 00 00 04 00 80 00 00 10 00 00 02 00 40 00 00 08 00 00 01 00 20 00 00 8C 37 DB 68 03 20 FB ED 96 65 00 00 00 00

**14-  IEND:**

49 45 4E 44

**15- Last 4 bytes**

```
 AE 42 60 82
```

***What are these ?***

Can some help me understand, points 11, 13 and  15 above?    And where are the Pixel values? The Image is having (128 x 68 pixels)

**Purpose of knowing these details:**

Once I know these details, I will generate my own 16 bit PNG image. I already have pixel values, so my job would be to introduce headers etc.
I dont know if there is software that can perform this job.

**UPDATE**

I understand now because of compression, I would not be able to locate the pixel values.

I got the idea that I can write a file in OpenCV and save it as png. Well now my direct question is: I have a **binary** file having gray-scale 16 bit-pixel values.  Can I write this in OpenCV as 16 bit PNG ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although it might be interesting to learn about what PNG Images actually are, and how the image is actually represented in the file, you don't need to know this to generate a PNG file.

Note that PNG uses lossless compression, which means you won't get two bytes per pixel.

You can generate your image in a program and output it in PNG format using many of the libraries that there are out there.
For example, you can make your image in OpenCV and then output it with [`imWrite`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#cv-imwrite). One of the parameters can make it output to a PNG.

---

If you have the gray-scale 16-bit pixel values, then you can put them into a [`Mat`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html).

Then convert that to an IplImage: [Converting cv::Mat to IplImage*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664187/converting-cvmat-to-iplimage)

Then you can output it to a file.

Comment: I just noticed about Compression, so its fine I would not get exact Pixel values.  But Can you tell me about 11 and 15?

Comment: Thanks, your answer is very helpful to me. I will test it and then post the result.

Comment: +1 But I don't fully agree with "You just wasted your time". Learning about the internals of PNG might not be necessary for your current task, but it's learning nevertheless.

Comment: Guys today I have learned both inside and out side of the PNG! Thanks for your help guys! And yes learning low level details are important b'coz it makes things future proof.

Comment: Okay, you're right about that. My statement was quite aggressive.

Answer (score 3):

Just for completeness (eboix's answer is right on the spot)

> 11- What is the following data?
>
> C6 25 AA 3E 00 00 00 C2

Each chunk ends with a [CRC](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#5DataRep) (4 bytes), and starts with 4 bytes that tell its length.
So, `C6 25 AA 3E` is the CRC of the previous chunk (IHDR) and `00 00 00 C2` (194) is the length of the following (IDAT) chunk.

In the same way, the last 4 bytes is the CRC of the IEND chunk.

Answer (score 3):

I did not look too carefully but from looking at the structure...

Q11.
C6 25 AA 3E = CRC32
00 00 00 C2 = Size of next chunk

Q13.
check the png spec's you referred to earlier that looks like the IDAT chunk you allready know the compression applied to it!

Q15.
AE 42 60 82 = CRC32